# Does Z370-A PRO Have On Board Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, gaming

Does Z370-A PRO Have On Board WiFi and if so how would go about installing the drivers. I currently am not sure if this is the case and I am having trouble finding the means to use the wifi on my pc or I having to purchase a wifi card and install it, as the ethernet cord I a currently using will not be available very soon.

Answer (score 0):

No, this motherboard does not have built-in WIFI.

MSI: You can use any PCIe or USB-based adapter for WiFi.